# Line integral over a Lemniscate using Cauchy integral formula

Tags: integration, line-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

Let be $L=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R²}\mid ((x-1)²+y²)((x+1)²+y²)=1 \}$. Let be path $\gamma$ the edge of $L$ so that the negative part goes in mathematical positive way and the positive part goes in mathematical negative way (like drawing the infinity symbol). Calculate $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{1-z²}$ using Cauchy's integral formula.

I thought to first divide the path $\gamma$ to $\gamma_1$, which is on the left/negative side and $\gamma_2$, which is on the right/positive side. Taking $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z}$ we get $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{1-z²}=-\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-1}dz=\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{f(z)}{z-1}dz - \int_{\gamma_2}\frac{f(z)}{z-1}dz=0$. The reason I took the negative of the integral over the path $\gamma_1$ is because it goes clockweise and the Cauchy formula is for counterclockwise integrals.

Can someone say if this is right what I did here? I appreciate hints much more than solutions.

Comment: Your result isn't correct. You need to draw a diagram of $\gamma$ and see where the poles $z = \pm 1$ of $\frac{1}{1-z^2} = \frac12(\frac{1}{1-z}+ \frac{1}{1+z})$ lie

Comment: They are inside of the lemniscate, located on the x-axis.

Comment: Ok so $\gamma = \gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$ both closed (rectifiable) curves. What can you say of $\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{1}{1-z}dz$ knowing $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is holomorphic/analytic on $Re(z) \le 0$ ?

Comment: Then the Integral should be equal to zero?

Comment: What theorem are you using ? And what for $\int_{\gamma_2} \frac{1}{1-z}dz$ ?..

Comment: If $g$ is a holomorphic function and $\alpha$ is a rectifiable path whose start point is equal to its end point, then we have $\oint_{\alpha}g(z)dz=0$.

And if $z_0$ lies outside of $\alpha$ then we have also that $\int_{\alpha}\frac{g(z)}{z-z_0}dz=0$

Comment: yes it is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem for applying it you need $g(z)$ to be holomorphic on a simply connected open containing the contour. This is also the way you prove the Cauchy integral formula